HomeWindow Does Not Open After Closing LoginWindow at Application Startup
I have an application made with C# + WPF that contains two windows:

HomeWindow
LoginWindow

Before the application starts, I'm calling a dialog box that loads the LoginWindow, that is, if the UserId property is not filled in (as it always is not).
To do this, take a look at how I've set up my App.xaml and App.xaml.cs:
App.xaml:
<Application x:Class="LoginComFirebase.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginComFirebase"
             StartupUri="View/HomeWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

App.xaml.cs:
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static string UserId = string.Empty;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
            {
                LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
                bool? result = loginWindow.ShowDialog();

                if (result != true)
                {
                    Shutdown(); 
                    return;
                }
            }

            HomeWindow homeWindow = new HomeWindow();
            homeWindow.Show();
        }
    }

Inside my LoginWindow, I have a button that execute the following function:
private void LoginButtonClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.UserId = "user_ok";
    Close();
}

The big problem is that when I run my application, the dialog window (LoginWindow) disappears, but the main window (HomeWindow) is never loaded.
This causes my application to shut down. In my case, I would like the Login screen to appear first, before the Home screen is shown to the user.

Could it be the order, your closing the window before opening the main window. Maybe start by hiding it and not closing it. I don't think your able to call show after you have closed the login dialog.

This question is similar to WPF: application shutdown after closing a window.

When my dialog returns a boolean value (bool? result = loginWindow.ShowDialog();), automatically, that dialog box is being closed, regardless of whether I am calling the Close() method or not.
However, just because the window has been closed and we don't have another one open, the OnStartup method will still execute the next commands.
But, from the moment we try to open another window (homeWindow.Show();), this command will not work, because if you don't have a window open (or if the window being closed is the only one, as is my case), this can lead to a state where there is no visible window, resulting in the application closing (even if you try to open a new window a few milliseconds later).
A possible way to resolve this issue is to open a new window before returning the dialog box result:
private void LoginButtonClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.UserId = "user_ok";

    HomeWindow homeWindow = new HomeWindow();
    homeWindow.Show();

    DialogResult = true;
}

And don't forget to remove the StartupUri from App.xaml:
<Application x:Class="LoginComFirebase.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginComFirebase">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

